# MPAndroidChart: How to get zoomed chart width?

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I want the width of my view to be equal to the real line chart width (with zoom). I set visible x range. And try to get width with many ways. I tried:

```
chartBitmap.width * scaleX.toInt()
```

and

```
viewPortHandler.contentWidth() * scaleX.toInt()
```

and

```
val coefficient = xChartMax / visibleXRange
val chartWidth = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * coefficient
```

But I can't make my horizontal scroll bar content width (**red box**) to be equal with my line chart witdh:

[image: chart]

How can I do this?